# Requirements for the modulus in the Massey-Omura three pass protocol

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, three-pass-protocol

In the Massey-Omura three pass protocol:

- How many bits long should the prime modulus $M$ be in order to be secure?
- Should the $M$ be secret?
- Should the $M$ be generated every time or it could be reused to generate new keys?

Comment: I'd guess that it works like DH in that regard, you can use a shared public modulus, as long as it's big enough. 2048 bits or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many bits long should the prime modulus $M$ be in order to be
>   secure?

The modulus $M$ should be long enough to prevent discrete logarithms from being computable.
As of 2015 this means 2048 bits length is fine, but for other (official) recommendations you should consult [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/)

> Should the $M$ be secret?

You *can* make $M$ secret but making it public shouldn't affect security as long as it's large enough to prevent any discrete logarithm computations from succeeding.

> Should the M be generated every time or it could be reused to generate new keys?

Usually it is rather computationally intensive to generate such moduli. Again, you *can* generate a new modulus every time if you fear there may be unknown backdoors in public parameters or you want to dodge something like [Logjam](https://weakdh.org/), but if the modulus is long enough you *don't have to* generate new moduli on every connection.