# Selection of parameters for Massey-Omura Cryptosystem

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I have 4 questions about Massey-Omura Cryptosystem.

1. Are there standards that define these parameters?
2. How to choose a group order?
3. What is better to take the function f?
4. What is the recommended key length?

Comment: helpful for num, 4 question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26911/requirements-for-the-modulus-in-the-massey-omura-three-pass-protocol?rq=1

Comment: unclear what you mean function f?